# How to hide undefined?

Tags: anychart

How to hide empty/undefined values for
chart type: anychart.stock();

Screen was made with next data:

```
 var dataTable2 = anychart.data.table();
        dataTable2.addData([
          ["2016-12-24", 518.40],
         ["2016-12-25",  519.34],
         
        ]);
    
        var dataTable3 = anychart.data.table();
        dataTable3.addData([
          ["2016-12-24",  undefined],
          ["2016-12-25",  524.34],
         
        ]);
        var mapping3 = dataTable3.mapAs(
            { value: 1}
          );
        var mapping2 = dataTable2.mapAs(
            { value: 1}
          );
```

[image]

With one undefined is not a big problem but what if I have 20? It would be take time to find defined value
It is useless information for my opinion and decreasing speed for understanding chart

The same result after manually delete field

```
  test_issue(){         
      function filterUndefinedPoints(data) {
        return data.filter((row) =>  row[1] !== undefined);
      } 

      var dataTable2 = anychart.data.table();
      dataTable2.addData([ // these are not filtered
        ["2016-12-24", 518.4],
        ["2016-12-25", 519.34],
      ]);
      
      var dataTable3 = anychart.data.table();
      dataTable3.addData(filterUndefinedPoints([ // these are filtered
    //    ["2016-12-24", undefined], // this will be removed
        ["2016-12-25", 524.34],
      ]));
      var mapping3 = dataTable3.mapAs({ value: 1 });
      var mapping2 = dataTable2.mapAs({ value: 1 });  

      var chart = anychart.stock();
      var plot = chart.plot(0);
    
      var a = plot.marker(mapping2);
      var b = plot.marker(mapping3);

      chart.container("container");
      chart.draw();

    }
```

Its happening when I have several markers in one plot. The markers dependent of dataset of each other but I dont' want it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function that filters out any entries that have `undefined` values:

```js
function filterUndefinedPoints(data) {
  return data.filter((row) => row[1] !== undefined);
}
```

Then use that when passing in your data points that can have `undefined` values:

```js
var dataTable2 = anychart.data.table();
dataTable2.addData([ // these are not filtered
  ["2016-12-24", 518.4],
  ["2016-12-25", 519.34],
]);

var dataTable3 = anychart.data.table();
dataTable3.addData(filterUndefinedPoints([ // these are filtered
  ["2016-12-24", undefined], // this will be removed
  ["2016-12-25", 524.34],
]));
var mapping3 = dataTable3.mapAs({ value: 1 });
var mapping2 = dataTable2.mapAs({ value: 1 });
```

Comment: I tried bit  it don't work. 
I'm getting the same result after removing field manually too.